# CMake builds when in directory, but it won't when add_subdirectory is used

Tags: cmake

I don't know how to explain why, but when I run cmake in a directory it works fine. If I go one level up and in the CMakeLists.txt use Add_SubDirectory then it is broken.

I will put the steps down.

1. mkdir MyFolder
2. git clone https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-c.git

These steps work to prove that the build works:

3. cd mariadb-connector-c
4. mkdir build && cd build
5. cmake -G Ninja ..
6. ninja

Ok that worked great. So next trying it one level up:

7. cd ../.. (Now located in "MyFolder")
8. Add a CMakeLists.txt with this source.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(mariadb VERSION 1.0.0)

add_subdirectory(mariadb-connector-c)
```

9. mkdir build & cd build
10. cmake -G Ninja ..

And now it blows up. Does anyone know why this is the case?

#### Edit

As requested here is the first error of the log when it is built as a sub project.

```
Determining if files select.h exist failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/questionable/Desktop/Programming/source-mariadb/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/ninja cmTC_c650d && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_c650d.dir/HAVE_SELECT_H.c.o
FAILED: CMakeFiles/cmTC_c650d.dir/HAVE_SELECT_H.c.o 
/usr/bin/cc   -Wunused -Wlogical-op -Wno-uninitialized -Wall -Wextra -Wformat-security -Wno-init-self -Wwrite-strings -Wshift-count-overflow -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-undef -Wno-unknown-pragmas -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_c650d.dir/HAVE_SELECT_H.c.o   -c /home/questionable/Desktop/Programming/source-mariadb/build/CMakeFiles/CheckIncludeFiles/HAVE_SELECT_H.c
/home/questionable/Desktop/Programming/source-mariadb/build/CMakeFiles/CheckIncludeFiles/HAVE_SELECT_H.c:2:10: fatal error: select.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <select.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.


Source:
/* */
#include <select.h>


int main(void){return 0;}
```

Comment: Define "blows up."  What errors do you get?

Comment: It's an entire log of errors, pages and pages. The first error is that it can't find <select.h> and the last error is that -lpthread doesn't exist.

Comment: Unless the documentation/README for a CMake project is explicitly specifies that it can be built as a **subproject**, no one **guarantees** that it can be built in that manner. Well, it is usually a good **assumption**, that a particular project could be built as a subproject. But if you want us to debug that usage, you need to be more detailed about your problem. E.g. show the **exact error message** you got. As usual, if your error log is too lengthy, it is normally sufficient to show only the first error message.

Comment: No, do not show content of `CMakeErrorLog.txt` file: these error messages are mostly not "real". Show the error message in the CMake **output**.

Comment: Please post the entire log of errors, all the pages and all the pages. Please also compile with verbose (`make VERBOSE=1` or `cmake --verbose --build ..`) for even more pages of logs of errors and post it all then. You posted parts of CMakeErrorLog that was used for detection of `select.h` - I do not feel it's even related to the problem, it's just detecting `select.h`, and sure it should be missing, it's `sys/select.h`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors I get at cmake configure stage from your source are:

```
CMake Deprecation Warning at mariadb-connector-c/CMakeLists.txt:5 (CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED):
  Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


CMake Warning (dev) at mariadb-connector-c/CMakeLists.txt:19 (PROJECT):
  Policy CMP0048 is not set: project() command manages VERSION variables.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0048" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The following variable(s) would be set to empty:

    PROJECT_VERSION
    PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR
    PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR
    PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Error at mariadb-connector-c/cmake/install_plugins.cmake:11 (INSTALL):
  INSTALL TARGETS given no LIBRARY DESTINATION for module target "dialog".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  mariadb-connector-c/cmake/plugins.cmake:82 (INSTALL_PLUGIN)
  mariadb-connector-c/plugins/auth/CMakeLists.txt:30 (REGISTER_PLUGIN)
  mariadb-connector-c/plugins/CMakeLists.txt:7 (INCLUDE)
  mariadb-connector-c/CMakeLists.txt:392 (INCLUDE)


CMake Error at mariadb-connector-c/cmake/install_plugins.cmake:11 (INSTALL):
  INSTALL TARGETS given no LIBRARY DESTINATION for module target
  "client_ed25519".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  mariadb-connector-c/cmake/plugins.cmake:82 (INSTALL_PLUGIN)
  mariadb-connector-c/plugins/auth/CMakeLists.txt:54 (REGISTER_PLUGIN)
  mariadb-connector-c/plugins/CMakeLists.txt:7 (INCLUDE)
  mariadb-connector-c/CMakeLists.txt:392 (INCLUDE)


CMake Error at mariadb-connector-c/cmake/install_plugins.cmake:11 (INSTALL):
  INSTALL TARGETS given no LIBRARY DESTINATION for module target
  "caching_sha2_password".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  mariadb-connector-c/cmake/plugins.cmake:82 (INSTALL_PLUGIN)
  mariadb-connector-c/plugins/auth/CMakeLists.txt:70 (REGISTER_PLUGIN)
  mariadb-connector-c/plugins/CMakeLists.txt:7 (INCLUDE)
  mariadb-connector-c/CMakeLists.txt:392 (INCLUDE)


CMake Error at mariadb-connector-c/cmake/install_plugins.cmake:11 (INSTALL):
  INSTALL TARGETS given no LIBRARY DESTINATION for module target
  "sha256_password".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  mariadb-connector-c/cmake/plugins.cmake:82 (INSTALL_PLUGIN)
  mariadb-connector-c/plugins/auth/CMakeLists.txt:81 (REGISTER_PLUGIN)
  mariadb-connector-c/plugins/CMakeLists.txt:7 (INCLUDE)
  mariadb-connector-c/CMakeLists.txt:392 (INCLUDE)


CMake Error at mariadb-connector-c/cmake/install_plugins.cmake:11 (INSTALL):
  INSTALL TARGETS given no LIBRARY DESTINATION for module target
  "auth_gssapi_client".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  mariadb-connector-c/cmake/plugins.cmake:82 (INSTALL_PLUGIN)
  mariadb-connector-c/plugins/auth/CMakeLists.txt:106 (REGISTER_PLUGIN)
  mariadb-connector-c/plugins/CMakeLists.txt:7 (INCLUDE)
  mariadb-connector-c/CMakeLists.txt:392 (INCLUDE)


CMake Error at mariadb-connector-c/cmake/install_plugins.cmake:11 (INSTALL):
  INSTALL TARGETS given no LIBRARY DESTINATION for module target
  "mysql_clear_password".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  mariadb-connector-c/cmake/plugins.cmake:82 (INSTALL_PLUGIN)
  mariadb-connector-c/plugins/auth/CMakeLists.txt:126 (REGISTER_PLUGIN)
  mariadb-connector-c/plugins/CMakeLists.txt:7 (INCLUDE)
  mariadb-connector-c/CMakeLists.txt:392 (INCLUDE)


CMake Error at mariadb-connector-c/cmake/install_plugins.cmake:11 (INSTALL):
  INSTALL TARGETS given no LIBRARY DESTINATION for module target "remote_io".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  mariadb-connector-c/cmake/plugins.cmake:82 (INSTALL_PLUGIN)
  mariadb-connector-c/plugins/io/CMakeLists.txt:7 (REGISTER_PLUGIN)
  mariadb-connector-c/plugins/CMakeLists.txt:7 (INCLUDE)
  mariadb-connector-c/CMakeLists.txt:392 (INCLUDE)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/kamil/tmp/test/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/kamil/tmp/test/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Looks like there's a problem in [install.cmake](https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-c/blob/3.1/cmake/install_plugins.cmake). Looks like strangely `INSTALL_PLUGINDIR` is not set, so `DESTINATION` argument to `install` has no parameter... :/ . The following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(mariadb VERSION 1.0.0)

set(INSTALL_PLUGINDIR /some/path)
add_subdirectory(mariadb-connector-c)
```

allows building the project.